# Configure Masstransit 2.0.0.5 with Ninject 2.0

Tags: ninject-2, masstransit

Probably being dumb here.. but its getting late :)

I am trying to use MassTransit with Ninject.  I know there isnt as much love for Ninject with MT but I want to continue regardless.. and maybe help out evntualy.

Examples I have found so far appear to require that base class MassTransitModuleBase is used from MassTransit.NinjectIntegration;

However in 2.0.0.5 this doesnt appear - has this changed?  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They likely are still old, pre-2.0 examples. 2.0 of MT has been updated to take containers out of the core. In fact, with 2.0 you can use it without a container to get you up and started.

The Cashier part of one of the samples, https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/master/src/Samples/Starbucks/Starbucks.Cashier, uses NInject. Ideally this can get you moving forward a little bit more. If not, feel free to post on the mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss.

Comment: Ahyeah.. I see now (after sleep and coffee!)..
Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant, glad I could be of help.